Problems with desktop mode responsiveness to mobile mode (NAV and Profile Picture menu)
I have a code that when it is in size desktop works the expected mode, but when it goes to mobile mode I can not separate the profile photo from the Hamburger menu and leave it fixed in the upper left corner.
Desktop mode:
https://i.sstatic.net/VDrOH3th.png
Mobile mode:
https://i.sstatic.net/4a5bIJEL.png
https://i.sstatic.net/f7UJ2R6t.png
Expected mode:
https://i.sstatic.net/vT6HHN0o.png
https://i.sstatic.net/mLLkd8vD.png
Code:
https://github.com/Vicentebg/Test/
Please someone help me solve, I already searched for answers on Google, ChatgPT and Claude.
I've tried to use some changes in CSS but the profile photo never leaves the submenu.
I've tried to remove the photo from NAV but in desktop mode it is on top of the "EngageFlow", I don't know how to adjust all these parameters if someone can give me the way to solve I would thank you a lot.

Uma pergunta sobre este problema já foi postada e lá foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
